# Financing with two mortgages: a thing of the past?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, second-mortgage

Back in 2006, our mortgage broker easily got us two mortgages for use when purchasing a home with 10% down:

- A non-conforming ("jumbo") loan with 80% LTV requirements covering 80% of the purchase, and
- A HELOC for the remaining 10%

Would a scheme like that work after 2008, in particular in 2013? If not, are there other financing schemes that can be used to purchase a house with a low (five to ten percent) down payment when the amount of financing exceeding the "conforming" limits (708K in our area)?

Answer (score 4):

I doubt it. I researched it a bit when I was shopping for a HELOC, and found no bank giving HELOC for more than 80% LTV. In fact, most required less than 80%. Banks are more cautious now.

If the bank is not willing to compromise on the LTV for the first mortgage - either look for another bank, or another place to buy. I personally would not consider buying something I cannot put at least 20% downpayment on. It means that such a purchase is beyond means.

Comment: "It means that such a purchase is beyond means." Not necessarily: it just means that one does not have a down payment, that's all. For example, if I could get a loan to finance 95% of the purchase price, the monthly payment would still amount to under 20% of my monthly income - well within my means by any imaginable standard.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight until you lose your job...

Comment: The "until you lose your job" argument applies to purchases with 20%+ down, wouldn't you agree? I mean, the bank wouldn't let you skip a payment if you buy with 5% or with 95% down.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight of course. But my reasoning (not always true, of course) is that if you cannot save enough for 20% downpayment, you probably aren't going to have enough of a cushion to fall at. Banks usually ask about your savings and assets, not just your income, but for most parts they use similar reasoning.

Comment: +1 - but, what happened to "call the local brokers"? Really, I think there are always deals to be made, not every bank is identical.

Comment: my thoughts were already covered

Comment: 1.) you didn't answer the question just left your opinion.  I was offered a piggy back loan on my upcoming purchase, but I declined.
2.) I felt you were incorrect about your 20% opinion.  Lots of people did, could, and would finance for less.  Lots of first time buyers, people who are interested in investing cash immediately in their purchase, or people who might want to leave additional resources they have in place.  No need for condescension about what one could afford, that wasn't the question.

Comment: @Pablitorun so you don't think the first sentence answers the question?

Comment: @littleadv not really.  It is just your experience.  I had an opposite experience with my mortgage broker.

Comment: @Pablitorun so why don't you write an answer then? I'm not quite certain why my experience is not as valid as yours though... And what's wrong with my experience exactly? Are you saying I'm wrong in something? Or you just consider "I don't think so" not a valid response? Because there's plenty of opinionated answers on this site, you know

Comment: @littleadv I don't think anyone's individual experiences are worthwhile answers to this question.  That's why I didn't leave mine.  I don't think your answer is "wrong", but it would have been really been better suited as a comment.

Comment: @Pablitorun Almost all answers are based on personal experience or knowledge here. Very rarely I quote laws or regulations, yet you can see by my ratings that people actually do consider my answers useful, including this one. I do try to help people, even if my answer is less than perfect.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few of ways to do this:

- Ask the seller if they will hold a Vendor Take-Back Mortgage or VTB. They essentially hold a second mortgage on the property for a shorter amortization (1 - 5 years) with a higher interest rate than the bank-held mortgage. The upside for the seller is he makes a little money on the second mortgage. The downsides for the seller are that he doesn't get the entire purchase price of the property up-front, and that if the buyer goes bankrupt, the vendor will be second in line behind the bank to get any money from the property when it's sold for amounts owing.
- Look for a seller that is willing to put together a lease-to-own deal. The buyer and seller agree to a purchase price set 5 years in the future. A monthly rent is calculated such that paying it for 5 years equals a 20% down payment. At the 5 year mark you decide if you want to buy or not. If you do not, the deal is nulled. If you do, the rent you paid is counted as the down payment for the property and the sale moves forward.
- Find a private lender for the down payment. This is known as a "hard money" lender for a reason: they know you can't get it anywhere else. Expect to pay higher rates than a VTB.

Ask your mortgage broker and your real estate agent about these options.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get a HELOC, to the best of my knowledge, without actually "owning" the house.

If you get an 80% mortgage (of the purchase price - not the appraised value, btw), you still need 20% as a down payment.

Once you own the home, you can apply for a HELOC ... presuming you have enough equity (eg, the purchase price is $40k less than the appraised value).

---

We haven't looked at the norm, at least where I live, of 5% down for a traditional mortgage and 3.5% for an FHA (which your question touches on).

If you can do 5% down, on a $1,000,000 mortgage you need $50,000 on the day of closing. If the home is worth (ie appraises for) $1,250,000, you're getting 20% of the house "for free". Presuming the bank(s) will go for it, you could likely then open a HELOC for *as much as* $250,000 (again, depending on individual lender rules).

**tl;dr**:
If you don't have the money ready on the day of signing (via seasoning, if it is a loan/gift, or because you have been saving), you cannot afford the house.

---

To clarify from comments with the OP, I am in no way speaking to the buyer's ability to afford the monthly payments - this is only about affording the initial costs associated with the home buying process (down payment, closing, whatever else the bank(s) require, etc).

Comment: "You can't get a HELOC, to the best of my knowledge, without actually "owning" the house." We got HELOC as a second *purchase* loan on the day of closing back in 2005, so you definitely *could* get one back at the day. As far as your comment on the "cannot afford the house" goes, that's far from being an accepted fact.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - and that was 2005. This is 2013.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, wrt to being able to afford the house: if you don't have the money for it, you, by definition, cannot afford it. You may have that money via a loan (mortgage), cash (savings, gift, etc), or a combination. But if you don't have the money, you can't buy it because the seller won't sell.

Comment: If servicing the debt plus taxes plus maintenance plus insurance takes less than 20% of your income, you definitely *can* afford the house - and that's a fact. The amount of downpayment has nothing whatsoever to do with this: it determines the way the risk is split between you and the bank issuing the loan. Statistically, 20% downpayment translates into virtually zero risk to bank's interest in the property.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - I'm not talking about affording the home *after* the purchase: this is entirely about affording the *purchase* itself :). If you don't have the prerequisites to buy, you cannot afford it.

Comment: I'm sorry, [your comment](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21750/financing-with-two-mortgages-a-thing-of-the-past/21859?noredirect=1#comment30717_21859) doesn't make a slightest bit of sense to me.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - then there's some kind of disconnect. If you need $5000 *on the day of signing* to buy a home, and you only have $2500, you cannot afford the home. In the wake of the housing bubble burst, the feds decided 100% loans would no longer be allowed. And they made mortgage rules such that you need at least 3.5% down for an FHA and at east 5% down for traditional mortgages. Those amounts ***cannot*** be loans - they must be "real" money (saved, gifted, earned, etc). If you don't have the down payment, you cannot afford the home.

Comment: Now I see where the disconnect is: you put an equal sign between feds decision not to underwrite certain types of loans (e.g. 100% ones, or >80% when the amount exceeds area-specific limits) and the borrowers ability to afford a home. However, it's only a rule: it's here today, it wasn't there a few years back, and it may or may not be there in the future. Fundamentally, if one has cash flow that lets him service the debt, then he can afford whatever is bought on credit. There's also a credit risk that determines the interest on the loan, but that is a separate story.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - you're right about the transient nature of regulations. However, given that you asked the question in the context of 2013, it doesn't really matter what *might* change in the future :)

Answer (score 2):

Depends on where we are in the credit cycle.

When banks are scared like in 07 to 11, good luck.  Now (13), they'll probably start begging you.  There are more regulations that prevent it now, but they'll probably be eased as they usually are during good times.

If the banks won't help you, private investors might.  Just find your local mortgage investor club.

Comment: I never knew mortgage investor clubs existed! It turns out there's one within ten-minute drive from where I live. Thank you very much for the info!